# Continuity definition and theorem in a topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

This is an extremely common theorem, I have a function $f$ that maps $f:(X,\mathscr{S})\to(Y,\mathscr{T})$. I want to show that $f$ is continuous if and only if for all $V\in \mathscr{T}$, $f^{-1}(V)\in \mathscr{S}.$

I know exactly how to do this using distant function, but now I want to prove it using the definition of continuity in a topological space.

I did the forward direction by assuming that $f$ is continuous at $x\in X$, then $\forall f(x)\in V\in \mathscr{T}$, $\exists \,U$ such that $f(U)\subset V$.

Then because $f$ is continuous, I took $f^{-1}$ of both sides (actually this is the step I questioned most), then I get $U\subset f^{-1}(V)$. But then what do I do next? Can I conlude that this implies that $f^{-1}(V)\in \mathscr{S}$?

Comment: Isn't the first paragraph the _definition_ of continuity?

Comment: Echoing what Arthur said, if that *isn't* your definition of continuous, what is?

Comment: that's what I was trying to prove, the definition is the one that says $f(U)\subset V$

Comment: This is the definition for continuity I am using: $f$ is continuous at $x\in X$, then $\forall f(x)\in V\in \mathscr{T}$, $\exists \,U$ such that $f(U)\subset V$. The first paragraph is a theorem similar to a theorem in real analysis, I just want to do this using the definition from topology

Comment: @Akaichan Just so you know, what you're trying to prove *is* the standard definition of continuous.

Comment: @MikeMiller: But then why is it a theorem in real analysis/ metric spaces? Isn't the definition for continuity what I stated above?

Comment: The definition you are using (according to your comment) is a definition of  **continuous at $x\in X$**. So not a definition of *continuous*. BTW the set $U$ you mention must contain $x$.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you are trying to say now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful.

Let it be that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous at each element $x\in X$.

If $V$ is open in $Y$ then for each $x\in X$ with $f(x)\in V$ there is an open set $U_x\subset X$ with $x\in U_x$ and $f(U_x)\subset V$ or equivalently $U_x\subset f^{-1}(V)$.

As union of open sets $\bigcup_{x\in f^{-1}\left(V\right)}U_{x}$ is open in $X$ and  $f^{-1}(V)=\bigcup_{x\in f^{-1}\left(V\right)}U_{x}$ .

Proved is now that a function that is continous at each element of $x\in X$ is continuous.

---

Also the converse is true:

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous and $x\in X$ with $f\left(x\right)\in V$
and $V$ open in $Y$ then $U:=f^{-1}\left(V\right)$ is an open set
with $x\in U$ and $f\left(U\right)\subset V$. This shows that $f$ is continuous at $x$, and works for every $x\in X$.